Кортежи как неизменяемый тип данных
В литературе и документации написано, что кортеж — неизменяемый тип данных и  что после создания кортежа его элементы невозможно изменить. Однако если один из элементов кортежа - список, то мы можем изменить элементы этого списка (поскольку списки относятся к изменяемым типам данных). Почему же утверждают, что кортеж неизменяемый тип данных, если при наличии в нем списка, элементы списка можно изменить? Ломается логика.

Имеется ввиду, что нельзя добавить новый ОБЪЕКТ или удалить старый ОБЪЕКТ.

Нет не ломается. Дело в том, что кортеж хранит ссылку на список, а не сам список, если вы попытаетесь обратится к кортежу по индексу и заменить в нём какой-то элемент - это вызовет ошибку. В то время как если добавить элемент в список, адрес в памяти на этот список не измениться, следовательно, считается, что объект не изменился, а значит логика не нарушена мы не меняли никакой элемент в кортеже.

Сделала для наглядности пример. Элемент кортежа взяла список. попыталась изменить элемент кортежа(список) -выдало ошибку. Спасибо за пояснение!

Нет не ломается. Кортеж хранит ссылку на список, а не сам список. Если вы попытаетесь обратится к кортежу по индексу и заменить в нём какой-то элемент - это вызовет ошибку (например, ссылку на один список ссылкой на другой). В то время как если добавить элемент в список, ссылка (адрес этого списка в памяти) не измениться, следовательно, считается, что объект не изменился, а значит логика не нарушена - мы не меняли никакой элемент в кортеже.
